# Remove duplicates on the combination of Name and Age using Scala and print results, do not use high level API/Framework like pandas /spark-sql etc

Tags: scala

• Please do not use high level API/Framework like pandas /spark-sql etc.
• Solve this problem by using simple data structures given in a Scala language.

Dataset -

```
Name,Age,Location 
Rajesh,21,London
Suresh,28,California
Sam,26,Delhi
Rajesh,21,Gurgaon
Manish,29,Bengaluru
```

This is what I have tried:

```
val list =
  Source
    .fromFile("/home/nikhil/Desktop/Datasets/abc.csv").drop(1)
    .getLines()
    .filter(line => !line.isEmpty)
    .map { line =>
      val value = line.split(",")
      (value(0), value(1))
    }.toList

  val test = list.toSet //doesn't preserve the order


 //#To preserve the order
//  val test = list.distinct 

OR use drop(1) while reading the file, that will skip the first line of the file contains (Name, Age, Location).

test.foreach(println)

output:-
(Rajesh,21)
(Suresh,28)
(Sam,26)
(Manish,29)
```

Comment: What have you tried? Can you give us a **MCVE**?

Comment: Please edit the question to provide that code. Also, as far as I can see, that only shows how to read the dataset, what have you tried of the filtering?

Comment: val list = Source.fromFile("/home/nikhil/Desktop/Datasets/abc.csv").getLines().filter(line => !line.isEmpty)
      .map(line =>{
      val value = line.split(",")
      (value(0), value(1))
    })
      .toList

Comment: I tried to use Set to remove the duplicates..Set(list)

Comment: A **Set** won't work because you can have the same name and age with different locations. Anyways: I am pretty sure you can solve your problem by giving a look to the scaladoc: https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html

Comment: val a = list.toSet.toList
    a.foreach(println)

o/p - Suresh,28)
(Name,Age)
(Sam,26)
(Manish,29)
(Rajesh,21)

which is not ordered..pls help on this..

Comment: I told you a **Set** won't work. Take a look to the documentation, read all the methods, check what they do, take in mind your task. You only need to call one method on your list.

Comment: Does the order really matter? Also, giving you are only removing duplicates according to name and age, what happens with location? you should preserve the first one? the last one? all of them? How do you need to print the results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're on Scala 2.13.x then the new `distinctBy()` is an option.

```
  .   //readLines(), filter(), drop(1), whatever
  .
  .
  .distinctBy(s => s.take(s.lastIndexOf(",")))
  .foreach(println)
//Rajesh,21,London
//Suresh,28,California
//Sam,26,Delhi
//Manish,29,Bengaluru
```

---

Alas, no `distinctBy()`. Oh well, there's always `foldLeft()`.

```
  .foldLeft(Set.empty[String]){ case (seen, str) =>
    val substr = str.take(str.lastIndexOf(","))
    if (!seen(substr)) println(str)  //send to StdOut
    seen + substr
  }
```

Comment: Yes, tried the same but i was using Scala 2.11.x so couldn't use distinctBy() option.

Comment: Its not working..i think we can't use take with str as its [String, String]..

Comment: @NikhilMittal' **Don't** `split()` each line to create tuples. It's not needed. This code was tested and it works fine on each line of unmodified text.

Comment: Trying to mark accepted but m very new to stack overflow pls help ..i will surely mark your answer..thanks